# Retrieving an Record Problem

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Okay, that may not be the best subject...

I am setting up an approval workflow within an application. I pass the username and the dollar amount to the subprocedure and figure out what workflow I need to use for the approval process. I thought I had this working until I try to handle the condition when the user hasn't been setup.

So in my table I have:

```
wfid    wfuser    wfamt
1         user1      0
2         user2      0
2         user2      10000.00
```

Now if user3 tries to send something to the workflow, it shouldn't go becuase they are not setup. (Please note I have another table that contains the actual flow definition)

I had this code to retrieve the correct workflow:

```
     setgt (userId:amount) ARWFR1;
     readp ARWFR1;
     return wfid;
```

Obviously this works if the user is properly setup. However, throw our user3 sinareo back in and it won't work right. So then I tried:

```
     setgt (userId:amount) ARWFR1;
     readpe (userId) ARWFR1;
     if (%eof());
       return 0;
     endif;
     return wfid;
```

This is not working as I had expected. I am sure I am missing obvious, can you see it? I hope my current logic is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me can be found at: http://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200809/msg00509.html